# Creating yaml files from template in golang

Tags: go, go-templates

I want to create a yaml file from a current tmpl file. Basically I want to insert values in the `sample.tmpl` files stored in the `/templates` folder and create a new yaml file in the same folder `sample.yml`

My `sample.tmpl` looks like

```
url : {{ .host }}
namespace: {{ .namespace }}
```

I'm using the following function:

```golang
func ApplyTemplate(filePath string) (err error) {
    // Variables - host, namespace
    type Eingest struct {
        host      string
        namespace string
    }

    ei := Eingest{host: "example.com", namespace: "finance"}
    var templates *template.Template
    var allFiles []string
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    for _, file := range files {
        filename := file.Name()
        fullPath := filePath + "/" + filename
        if strings.HasSuffix(filename, ".tmpl") {
            allFiles = append(allFiles, fullPath)
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("Files in path: ", allFiles)

    // parses all .tmpl files in the 'templates' folder
    templates, err = template.ParseFiles(allFiles...)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    s1 := templates.Lookup("sample.tmpl")
    s1.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "sample.yml", ei)
    fmt.Println()
    return
}
```

`s1.ExecuteTemplate()` writes to `stdout`. How can I create a new file in the same folder? I believe something similar is used to build kubernetes yaml files. How do we achieve this using golang template package?

Comment: if yaml was a good idea, there would be a yaml package in golang stdlib. Please don't use yaml. Never.

Comment: Most intelligent gopher.

Comment: Hey sorry much time have passed since you asked this question, how did you end up generating a yaml from the combination of a template file and override yaml in go?

Answer (score 2):

First: since you've already looked up the template, you should use `template.Execute` instead, but the same works with `ExecuteTemplate`.

[text.Template.Execute](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Execute) takes a [io.Writer](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) as first argument. This is an interface with a single method: `Write(p []byte) (n int, err error)`.

Any type that has that method implements the interface and can be used as a valid argument. One such type is a [os.File](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File). Simply create a new `os.File` object and pass it to `Execute` as follows:

```golang
// Build the path:
outputPath := filepath.Join(filepath, "sample.yml")

// Create the file:
f, err := os.Create(outputPath)
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}

defer f.Close() // don't forget to close the file when finished.

// Write template to file:
err = s1.Execute(f, ei)
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}
```

**Note**: don't forget to check whether `s1` is nil, as documented in [template.Lookup](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Lookup).